# How to create a .bat file to input IP address and run nbtstat -a command

Tags: networking, google-chrome, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

Any suggestions? This is a wrong code:

```
@echo off
echo Enter IP address of remote computer:
set /p ip=

nbtstat -a  %ip%
```

Comment: Try changing your 3rd line to `set /p ip=IP:`

Answer (score 2):

Run nbtstat -A instead of nbtstat -a. -A switch accepts ip addresses. Where -a accepts remote names.

Comment: It keeps me run this loop..
Enter IP address of remote computer:
10.164.181.245

Enter IP address of remote computer:
10.164.181.245

Enter IP address of remote computer:


Enter IP address of remote computer:
10.164.181.245